# How to pass QTextStream as parameter qt c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to pass a QTextStream as a parameter to a function. I do it like this.

function:

```
void someFunc(QTextStream* ss)
{
    ss << "wow";
}
```

function call

```
QTextStream ss(&file);
someFunc(&ss);
```

And when I interact with the thread in the function I get the error:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('QTextStream *' and 'string')
```

Comment: Does it work if you do `(*ss) << "wow";`?

Comment: Change `void someFunc(QTextStream* ss)`  to `void someFunc(QTextStream & ss)` and `someFunc(&ss);` to `someFunc(ss);`

Comment: Use `(*ss) << "wow";`

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks, this works. Haven't tried other options, but I think they work too.

Comment: Yes, they have the same result but express different meanings. While both can be used to modify a QTextStream (or derived) object, the pointer version also accepts `nullptr` values, saying that the presence of the object is optional. The reference says that it is not optional, and is likely closer to your intention in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to pass a QTextStream as parameter:

```
void myFunc(QTextStream& ts) {
  // do some stuffs with ts
}

QTextStream textStream;
myFunc(textStream);
```